# Creating a csv from a list of data of varying lengths and columns

Tags: csv, autohotkey

I have a list of data points for an old DCS system that i would like to migrate into a more manageable organization (a csv preferably).  I would like to make each entry type into it's own column.  In the end i would also like to convert it back to it's original format given the modified csv file. this is a couple examples of the entries:

```
{SYSTEM ENTITY 95UA114( )                                                      }  
&T DIGINHG                                                                      
&N 95UA114                                                                      
UNIT     = FD  
PTDESC   ="95C-101 COMPRESSOR S/D  "  
KEYWORD  ="C101 S/D"  
PRIMMOD  = HPFD01G        
ASSOCDSP ="HPFD01~1"  
$CDETAIL ="        "  
HWYNUM   = 08  
PNTBOXTY = DHP           
BOXNUM   = 8   
PTDISCL  = FULL          
LOADDEST = HG_HIWAY      
SLOTNUM  = 12  
INPTSSLT = 10  
NMBRINPT = 1   
$AUXUNIT = --  
$REALARM = 0     
DIGALFMT = STATE2        
DLYTIME  = 0   
CHOFSTPR = NOACTION      
CNFERRPR = EMERGNCY      
OFFNRMPR = EMERGNCY      
CRITSCAN = OFF           
CCRANK   = NEITHER       
EIPPCODE = --                    
EIPEVENT = ANY           
EIPENB   = ENABLE        
ALENBST  = ENABLE        
STATE2   ="S/D_BYP "  
STATE1   ="NORMAL  "  
UBOXCLR  = RED           
LBOXCLR  = GREEN       
OVERVAL  = ON          
INPTDIR  = DIRECT      
PNTBOXIN = 1   
PNTPCTY  = MODICON       
PCADDRI1 = 2097  
SPECIFI1 = 1
```

The first line (system entity) is not needed as the info is redundant. The columns (Unit, ptdesc) are not always the same however. I was planning on using autohotkey to do this, but if anyone has a better suggestion I'm all ears. Right now, I have the code that reads the file and separates each entity and splits each line at the `=` to determine the value of each column, but lining them up is proving to be a challenge. The only way I can think of to handle it would be to use a 2d array, but it will be cumbersome to write, and I'm sure there is a better/more efficient way (since the file is about 21k lines/500 entities).

```
numEntries = 0
AutoTrim, Off
outFile = test.csv
filedelete, %outfile%
filereadline, columns, columns.txt, 1
fileappend, TAG`,NAME`,%columns%`r`n, %outfile%
stringsplit, columns, columns,`,
numcolumns=%columns0%
msgbox %numcolumns%
Loop, Read, H3ALL.EB
{
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,=
    {
        i++
        data%i%=%A_LoopReadLine%
        continue
    }       
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,SYSTEM ENTITY
    {
        numEntries+=1
        if(numEntries > 1)
        {
            fileappend,`r`n,%outfile%
            Loop %i%
            {
                element := data%A_Index%
                stringsplit, element, element,=
                Loop %numcolumns%
                {
                    test1=%element1%
                    test2:=columns%A_Index%
                    if (test1=test2)
                    {
                        ;add to correct column
                    }
                }
            }
            data=
            i=0
        }
        continue
    }
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,&T
    {
        stringsplit, line, A_LoopReadLine,%A_SPACE%
        tag=%line2%
        fileappend,%tag%`,,%outfile%
        ;msgbox the tag is %tag%
        continue
    }
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,&N
    {
        stringsplit, line, A_LoopReadLIne,%A_SPACE%
        name=%line2%
        fileappend,%name%`,, %outfile%
        ;msgbox the name is %name%
        continue
    }   
}
msgbox DONE!
```

working code:

```
i=0
j=0
outFile = test.csv
filedelete, %outfile%
AutoTrim, off

filereadline, columns, columns.txt, 1
fileappend,%columns%`r`n,%outfile%
stringsplit, columns, columns,`,
numColumns=%columns0%

Loop, Read, H3ALL.EB
{
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,=
    {
        i++
        stringsplit, line, A_LoopReadLine,=
        loop %numColumns% {
            test1:=columns%A_Index%
            test2=%line1%
            if(test1=test2) {
                dataArray%A_Index%_%j%=%line2%
                ;msgbox column %test1% (%A_Index%) contains %line2%
            }
        }
        continue
    }       
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,SYSTEM ENTITY
    {
        j++
        i=0

        continue
    }
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,&T
    {
        i++
        stringsplit, line, A_LoopReadLine,%A_SPACE%
        dataArray%i%_%j%=%line2%
        continue
    }
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,&N
    {
        i++
        stringsplit, line, A_LoopReadLIne,%A_SPACE%
        dataArray%i%_%j%=%line2%
        continue
    }   
}
outerIndex=0
Loop %j% {
    outerIndex++
    Loop %numColumns% {
        cell:=dataArray%A_Index%_%outerIndex%
        fileappend,%cell%`,,%outfile%
    }
    fileappend,`r`n,%outfile%
}
```

Comment: what languages are at your disposal ?
using perl or python dictionaries , and a measured use of "eval" could solve the problem neatly, 


OTOH  you can split the file , then sort each of the 500 files , and use "join" in bash, to get a transposed matrix, (rows for columns.)

if you don't know any scripting language , check out python or ruby, for 500 records it is shorter than doing it manually including the tamp up. 
----

Comment: Please post your code. Also, what marks the end of such an entity definition? I assume it's a `}` !? Are there multiple entitites contained within one file?

Comment: i have added my code to the op.  honestly, the only language i really have any experience with is autohotkey. it served its purpose for an old job and i haven't had time to experiment with any others, although i really would like to get some perl experience.
as for the what ends a block, yes the "SYSTEM ENTITY" line is the line i look for to know my current block is done.

Comment: ended up getting it to work. added the working code to the op if anyone cares. lol

Answer (score 0):

got it working:

```
i=0
j=0
outFile = test.csv
filedelete, %outfile%
AutoTrim, off

filereadline, columns, columns.txt, 1
fileappend,%columns%`r`n,%outfile%
stringsplit, columns, columns,`,
numColumns=%columns0%

Loop, Read, H3ALL.EB
{
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,=
    {
        i++
        stringsplit, line, A_LoopReadLine,=
        loop %numColumns% {
            test1:=columns%A_Index%
            test2=%line1%
            if(test1=test2) {
                dataArray%A_Index%_%j%=%line2%
                ;msgbox column %test1% (%A_Index%) contains %line2%
            }
        }
        continue
    }       
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,SYSTEM ENTITY
    {
        j++
        i=0

        continue
    }
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,&T
    {
        i++
        stringsplit, line, A_LoopReadLine,%A_SPACE%
        dataArray%i%_%j%=%line2%
        continue
    }
    ifinstring, A_LoopReadLine,&N
    {
        i++
        stringsplit, line, A_LoopReadLIne,%A_SPACE%
        dataArray%i%_%j%=%line2%
        continue
    }   
}
outerIndex=0
Loop %j% {
    outerIndex++
    Loop %numColumns% {
        cell:=dataArray%A_Index%_%outerIndex%
        fileappend,%cell%`,,%outfile%
    }
    fileappend,`r`n,%outfile%
}
```

Comment: added. i cannot accept the answer til tomorrow according to the error box when i click accept

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution for you (I started writing it before you posted your own solution). I didn't realise you had a column file so I extract the column headings from the file.

```
outFile = test.csv
FileRead, test, H3ALL.EB
filedelete, %outfile%
columns := Object()

;get all the columns names
temp := RegExReplace(test, "`a)(=.*|{SYSTEM ENTITY .*)")
;sort and make unique
sort, temp, U

;make it an array
loop, parse, temp, `n
{   if(A_LoopField == "")
    {   continue
    }
    columns.Insert(A_loopfield)
}

;write the columns to file
for key, val in columns
{   FileAppend, % val ",", % outfile
}
FileAppend, `r`n, % outfile

;split the entries up
test := RegExReplace(test, "`a)\{SYSTEM ENTITY .*", "``")
entries := StrSplit(test , "``")

;write each entry as a row in the csv
for key, val in entries
{   if(val = "")
    {   continue
    }
    row := Object()
    loop, parse, val, `n
    {   StringSplit, data, A_LoopField, =
        row[data1] := data2
    }
    for key2, val2 in columns
    {   FileAppend, % row[val2] ",", % outfile
    }
    FileAppend, `r`n, % outfile
}
```